# Increment a string with both letters and numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string which i need to increment by 1 The string has both characters and numeric values.

The string layout i have is as follows "MD00494"

How would i increment this to "MD00496" & "MD00497" ect

If it was a normal string with numbers i would parse it to an int.

I have tried the following

```
 int i = int.Parse(sdesptchNo);
 i++;
 txtDispatchNo.Text = i.ToString();
```

Anyone any ideas how i would go about this.

Comment: Will 'D' in "MD00497" eventually become 'E'?

Comment: No D will always stay at d it wont be that big where i need to go past 3000

Comment: @Inkey: It doesn't matter that you won't need to go past 3000. You **must** specify what will happen if you go past 99999, unless you like code that can potentially exhibit unknown behavior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You first should figure out any commonality between the strings. If there is always a prefix of letters followed by digits (with a fixed width) at the end, then you can just remove the letters, parse the rest, increment, and stick them together again.

E.g. in your case you could use something like the following:

```
var prefix = Regex.Match(sdesptchNo, "^\\D+").Value;
var number = Regex.Replace(sdesptchNo, "^\\D+", "");
var i = int.Parse(number) + 1;
var newString = prefix + i.ToString(new string('0', number.Length));
```

Another option that might be a little more robust might be

```
var newString = Regex.Replace(x, "\\d+",
    m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + 1).ToString(new string('0', m.Value.Length)));
```

This would replace any number in the string by the incremented number in the same width – but leaves every non-number exactly the same and in the same place.

Comment: God bless PHP for providing `++$whatever` to increment any string!

Comment: @hpaknia, no idea what god has to do with that, but PHP won't cause a numeric increment if the string doesn't end in a number.

Comment: I have an answer for the second part of your comment. PHP does increment non-numeric values. Please take a look at https://rextester.com/QMF41107

Comment: @hpaknia: Exactly, if your number that you want to increment doesn't happen to be at the _end_ of the string, PHP increments whatever is at the end of the string, including letters. Same with overflows, strings like `foo213bar` or `foo9` are unlikely to result in what you want.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one Non-Regex way :P

```
string str = "MD00494";
string digits = new string(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
string letters = new string(str.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());

int number;
if (!int.TryParse(digits, out number)) //int.Parse would do the job since only digits are selected
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something weired happened");
}

string newStr = letters + (++number).ToString("D5");
```

output would be:

```
newStr = "MD00495"
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution though it would be worth adding this 

string newStr = letters + (++number).ToString($"D{digits.Length}");

this would allow for varying numbers of leading zeros

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you only need to increment the numeric portion of the string, and that the structure of the strings is always - bunch of non-numeric characters followed by a bunch of numerals, you can use a regular expression to break up the string into these two components, convert the numeric portion to an integer, increment and then concatenate back.

```
var match = Regex.Match("MD123", @"^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)$");
var num = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

var after = match.Groups[1].Value + (num + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not work if there is a number in the middle of the string e.g. XXX123YYY456, exceptions are thrown.
I have written a generic method that will increment the end of the string and you can pass it the minimum amount of digits.

```
public static string IncrementStringEnd(string name, int minNumericalCharacters = 1)
        {
            var prefix = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(name, @"\d+$");
            if (prefix.Success)
            {
                var capture = prefix.Captures[0];
                int number = int.Parse(capture.Value) + 1;
                name = name.Remove(capture.Index, capture.Length) + number.ToString("D" + minNumericalCharacters);
            }

            return name;
        }
```

Test Results:

MD00494 : MD00495

XXX123YYY456 : XXX123YYY457

SD50MRF999 : SD50MRF1000

SD50MRF9 : SD50MRF010

 For testing purposes https://dotnetfiddle.net/j1f6wh

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the position of the first digit in the string.
Then split the string into 2 fields.

0 1 2 3 4 5 6

M D 0 0 4 9 4

The first field will be the non numeric part "MD"
The second field will be the numeric part "00494"

Increment the numeric only part to "00495"

You will lose the leading zero's so you'll need to pad your new number with the same amount of zero's once you've incremented.

Then join the 2 fields.

Comment: I would look for the position of the last non-digit in the string, rather than the first digit, in case it is a string like `"Foo37Baz00123"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
int kod = int.Parse(Regex.Replace(sdesptchNo, "[^0-9]", "")) + 1;

string zeroStr=Regex.Replace(sdesptchNo, "[^0-9]", "");
string newZeroStr="";
for (int x=0;x<zeroStr.length;x++)
     if (zeroStr[x]=='0') newZeroStr=newZeroStr+"0"; 
     else break;

string newVal=Regex.Replace(sdesptchNo, "[0-9]", "") + newZeroStr + kod;
```

UPDATED: This will save your zero

Comment: This would lose the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
string digits = new string(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
string letters = new string(str.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
string newStr;
int number;

if (!int.TryParse(digits, out number)) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Something weird happened");
}
if (digits.StartsWith("0"))
{
  newStr = letters + (++number).ToString("D5");
}
else
{
  newStr = letters + (++number).ToString();
}
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

```
string sDispatchNo = "MS00914";
var pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]+";
var strPart = Regex.Match(sDispatchNo, pattern).Value;
var noPart = Regex.Replace(sDispatchNo, pattern, "");
var no = int.Parse(noPart);
var length = noPart.Length;
length = (no + 1)/(Math.Pow(10,length)) == 1 ? length + 1 : length; 
var output = strPart + (no + 1).ToString("D" + length);
```

Comment: This is a very generic that can be used for any large number. Steps: 1. Identify String part
2. Identify Number part and its length
3. Increament Number
4 Merge string and Number

Answer (score 0):

I use this to Increment/Decrement Barcodes

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the number portion of the string and adds 1 to it
/// </summary>
public static string IncrementNumbers(this string numString)
{
  if (numString.IsEmpty())
    return numString;
  else if (!numString.Where(Char.IsDigit).Any())
    return numString;
  else
  {
    string prefix = Regex.Match(numString, "^\\D+").Value;
    string number = Regex.Replace(numString, "^\\D+", "");
    int i = int.Parse(number) + 1;
    return prefix + i.ToString($"D{numString.Length - prefix.Length}");
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the number portion of the string and subtracts 1 from it
/// </summary>
public static string DecrementNumbers(this string numString)
{
  if (numString.IsEmpty())
    return numString;
  else if (!numString.Where(Char.IsDigit).Any())
    return numString;
  else
  {
    string prefix = Regex.Match(numString, "^\\D+").Value;
    string number = Regex.Replace(numString, "^\\D+", "");
    int i = int.Parse(number) - 1;
    return prefix + i.ToString($"D{numString.Length - prefix.Length}");
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Shortented IsNullOrWhiteSpace 
/// </summary>
public static bool IsEmpty(this string str)
{
  if (str.TrimFix() == null)
    return true;

  return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Trims the String and returns Null if it's empty space
/// </summary>
public static string TrimFix(this string rawString)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawString))
  {
    return rawString.Trim();
  }
  return null;
}
```