# How to increment the last part of string that contains a number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, linq

I have this serial :

```
string serialTXT = "SD50MRF999";
```

I want to increase it to "SD50MRF1000" not "SD51MRF000".

I tried this :

```
var prefix = Regex.Match(sdesptchNo, "^\\D+").Value;
var number = Regex.Replace(sdesptchNo, "^\\D+", "");
var i = int.Parse(number) + 1;
var newString = prefix + i.ToString(new string('0', number.Length));
```

But the result : it isolate "SD" and "50MRF1000"

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268931/increment-a-string-with-both-letters-and-numbers

Comment: Your problem is how to identify the last number in the string, not incrementing it. I think you're more likely to get an answer if you tag this with Regular-Expressions and change the title

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you are storing in a string what should be stored in a data type that separates the textual parts from the numeric parts. If you stored the data in the right format, you wouldn't need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) for this purposes usually:

```
string serialTXT = "SD50MRF01";
string intPart = string.Join("", serialTXT.Reverse().TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).Reverse());
int intP = int.Parse(intPart);
serialTXT = serialTXT.Remove(serialTXT.Length - intPart.Length) + 
            (intP < 10 ? "0" + (intP + 1) : (intP + 1).ToString());
```

> Result => "SD50MRF1000"

Just don't forget to add this to your using directives:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: "SD50MRF01" => "SD50MRF2" .. how  i can make the number in same format

Comment: @BassemKamalM You can check fir numbers fewer than 10 and then add a `"0"` at the first of them, as I have shown in my updated answer.

Comment: @S.Akbari You can use `ToString("00")` or `ToString("D2")` instead of the comparaison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to get the last digits, then convert those to a number, and tack it onto the end of the part of the string which didn't match:

```
string serialTXT = "SD50MRF999";
Regex re = new Regex( "([0-9]+)$"); /* digits at the end */
string end = re.Match(serialTXT).Value;
int newNum = int.Parse(end) + 1; /* we need a number to increment it */
string newSerial = serialTXT.Substring(0, serialTXT.Length - end.Length) + newNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regular-expressions answer would be to check the last character in the string to see if it's a number, and then the next one, etc, until you've got your number.

Answer (score 0):

Like @S.Akbari, I think Linq can be nice here. This snippet will work on string like `"SD50MRF50"`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str = "SD50MRF999";
    var digits = str.Reverse().TakeWhile(char.IsDigit);
    var number = digits.Select((x,i) => (x - '0') * Math.Pow(10, i)).Sum();
    var letters = str.Remove(str.Length - digits.Count());

    // use letters + (++number).ToString("00")
    // or letters + (++number).ToString("D2")
    // to write `01`, `02`, `03` etc.
    Console.WriteLine(letters + (++number));
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vILUYM)

Comment: thank you , it work fine ... only i need to validate that the last character is number

Comment: @S.Akbari ok perfect. :)

Comment: "SD50MRF01" => "SD50MRF2" .. how  i can make the number in same format

Comment: @BassemKamalM Something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SgJfVl)? (dont forgot to upvote the answer if you find it useful)