# Increment string letters and numbers only c#

Tags: c#, base36

A similar question was asked here : 
[Increment a string with both letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268931/increment-a-string-with-both-letters-and-numbers) except it increments only the numbers in the string, I want to increment **both** numbers and letters and only to letters and numbers, and not to anything else like `;+-*:=` characters.

Examples:

```
Z006GZYBA1 => Z006GZYBA2
        A9 => AA 
        AZ => B0 
1ZZZZZZZZZ => 2000000000
```

**EDIT:** What I've tried:

```
 public static string IncrementString(this string input)
    {
        string rtn = "A";
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            bool prependNew = false;
            var sb = new StringBuilder(input.ToUpper());
            for (int i = (sb.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (i == sb.Length - 1)
                {
                    var nextChar = Convert.ToUInt16(sb[i]) + 1;
                    if (nextChar > 90)
                    {
                        sb[i] = 'A';
                        if ((i - 1) >= 0)
                        {
                            sb[i - 1] = (char)(Convert.ToUInt16(sb[i - 1]) + 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prependNew = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb[i] = (char)(nextChar);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Convert.ToUInt16(sb[i]) > 90)
                    {
                        sb[i] = 'A';
                        if ((i - 1) >= 0)
                        {
                            sb[i - 1] = (char)(Convert.ToUInt16(sb[i - 1]) + 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prependNew = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            rtn = sb.ToString();
            if (prependNew)
            {
                rtn = "A" + rtn;
            }
        }

        return rtn.ToUpper();
    }
```

Comment: So show us the code you have tried so far & explain why it is not working as expected.

Comment: What is the allowable range of letters - just `A` .. `Z`? (i.e. 36 different symbols, including digits). And what is the maximum length of the strings?

Comment: Basically you should represent every string as just a number with that you can calculate. Tne add `1` for instance and convert that back to a string. However how this conversion works goes far beyond a simple question here - in particular as you didn´t provide any own idea or code that shows what you tried already.

Comment: what exactly is your use case, by the way?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I received this ID and was told the next reference will be an incremented value which is created immediately and safe to use. So I need to increment it myself.

Comment: What you are really looking at is a base-36 number (0-9 + A-Z) - there are several implementations available if you google that. Along the line @HimBromBeere suggested - you could create a class that has a single integer field that you do the arithmetic on & methods that convert to/from strings.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, A-Z and digits only. Max length unlimited or whatever the limit of a string is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (method is `IncrementBase36()` but I put it in a console app for demo purposes):

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IncrementBase36("Z006GZYBA1"));
            Console.WriteLine(IncrementBase36("A9"));
            Console.WriteLine(IncrementBase36("AZ"));
            Console.WriteLine(IncrementBase36("1ZZZZZZZZZ"));
        }

        public static string IncrementBase36(string numberBase36)
        {
            var digits = numberBase36.ToCharArray();
            bool carry = true;

            for (int i = digits.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if (carry)
                {
                    if (digits[i] == 'Z')
                    {
                        digits[i] = '0';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (digits[i] == '9')
                            digits[i] = 'A';
                        else
                            ++digits[i];

                        carry = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (carry)
                return '1' + new string(digits);
            else
                return new string(digits);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you want is to add `1` to a number using `radix = 36` (`10` digist + `26` letters):

```
private static string IncrementString(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

  HashSet<char> skip = new HashSet<char>(";+-*:=");
  int shift = 1;
  bool added = false; 
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length + 1);

  foreach (char c in value.Reverse()) {
    if (skip.Contains(c)) {
      sb.Append(c);

      continue;
    }

    int v = (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? c - '0'
          : (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? c - 'a' + 10
          : (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c - 'A' + 10
          : throw new FormatException("Invalid symbol");

    added = true;
    v += shift;
    shift = v / 36;
    v %= 36;

    sb.Append(v < 10 ? (char)('0' + v) : (char) ('A' + v - 10));
  }

  if (!added)
    throw new FormatException("Only delimiters. Nothing to add.");

  return string.Concat(sb.ToString().Reverse());
}
```

Let's have a look:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Z006GZYBA1",
    "A9",
    "AZ",
    "1ZZZZZZZZZ",
    "123:456:Abc:zzz", // test with delimiters 
  };

  string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,20} => {IncrementString(test)}"));

  Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
      Z006GZYBA1 => Z006GZYBA2
              A9 => AA
              AZ => B0
      1ZZZZZZZZZ => 2000000000
 123:456:Abc:zzz => 123:456:ABD:000
```